# What are the differences between baking in bulk and baking in smaller amounts?

Tags: baking, bulk-cooking

I know that you need different techniques and tools to bake in bulk. But do recipes need to be changed as well? How does one take a recipe that you would bake at home in a small batch (e.g. baking bread, pies, muffins, etc.) and then convert it into a bulk recipe?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, recipes need to be changed as well.

- The most important [IMHO] difference is leavening (yeast/baking powder/soda etc.)
- The next issue is ratios, once you get beyond 'doubling' a home recipe your ratios will get out of sync.
- When you multiply dry ingredients (other than yeast) do so **By Weight** rather than dry measure. (note for sugars in a yeast leavened recipe: sugar is often 'treated as' a 'wet ingredient', still multiply by weight, this will provide the correct amount of food for the yeast)

> Rule of thumb for yeast baking is to multiply everything but DO NOT
>   multiply the yeast for doing 2X or 4X. *When you are increasing the
>   recipe by 8X you double the original amount of **yeast***. Your rising time
>   may increase but that also happens with temperature variations.
>
> Rule of thumb for ***chemical leavening*** is to multiply carefully ALL
>   ingredients. If using baking soda and acid, sift the baking soda with
>   flour and mix the acid (vinegar, lemon juice, sour milk) with other
>   liquid ingredients. That way you don't lose rising power when mixing
>   more dough. 
>   But for chemical leavening, you have to bake the mix without it
>   sitting around. So you might weigh and set up 4X, 4X, 4X if you need
>   12X yield.[from [King Arthur Flour]](http://community.kingarthurflour.com/content/doubling-recipes-especially-leaving-agents)

---

> Home sized recipes can usually only be doubled safely. Beyond that,
>   due to rounding, the ratios within the recipe will get out of sync. We
>   have a number of pro resources here, take a look:
>   http://www.kingarthurflour.com/professional/flours.html([Ibid](http://community.kingarthurflour.com/content/doubling-recipes-especially-leaving-agents))

---

These are, obviously, only 'general guidelines, your mileage may vary with any given recipe.